# BeanInstantiationException Failed to instantiate org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

Getting issue after upgrading Spring boot version from 2.4.2 to 2.6.8 .When starting the server getting below error:

14:38:38,461 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."abc.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."abc.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'XYZESRepository' defined in com.x.y.elastic.repository.XYZESRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on ElasticsearchRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableElasticsearchRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method substring(java.lang.Integer) on null context object

---

XYZESRepository is like:

import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;

public interface XYZESRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<MyObject, String> {

}

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducible example for this?

Comment: When I started working for minimal reproducible code, I got the root cause in that process while debugging. The problem was while creating the bean SimpleElasticsearchRepository, it looks the expression defined in the entity MyObject. The expression defined, was not getting the name defined based on environment variable. The name of the environment variable was in upper case in entity but was actually defined as lower case in env file. I am not sure why was it working fine in boot version 2.4.2.